# How long did it take Captain Marvel to travel to Earth?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

At the start of *Avengers: Endgame*, Iron Man is at the brink of death and "thousands of light years from the nearest 7-11" when Captain Marvel shows up.  It appears like Captain Marvel  carries neither food nor oxygen, yet brings the spaceship to Earth before Iron Man dies.

**Question**: To rescue Iron Man (and Nebula), how long did it take Captain Marvel to travel to Earth?

Captain Marvel doesn't use the bifrost nor the space stone, she just carries the spaceship back to Earth.  She would have to do this rather quickly to ensure Iron Man gets back in time to eat an "American cheeseburger".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Less than a day

Firstly, Tony says in his message to Pepper that it's Day 22 and that the oxygen will run out "tomorrow morning".

Then, when Captain Marvel rescues the ship and brings it to Earth, Rhodey explains that

> ...it's been 23 days since Thanos came to Earth".

This indicates that Captain Marvel made the trip in 12 to 24 hours.

Comment: Is the message to Pepper what alerted them that Tony was still alive? The message is never broadcast so I doubt it, as that would mean that the message somehow travels faster than lightspeed.

Comment: @Parrotmaster Nope, she just found them by chance it appears. Possibly CM had been sent to find them when they didn't come back though,

Comment: I don't understand how you came to the 12 to 24 hours conclusion. Is there any reason why it couldn't be 11 hours or 25 hours for example?

Comment: @Paulie_D  Avengers are on Earth.  Tony was last known to be heading to Thanos' planet.  Long as they know where that planet was, he's probably traveling along a very narrow corridor of space to get from point A to point B.  Makes it pretty easy to find him, really.

Comment: Also, she has Kree tech on her suit - presumably it's capable of scanning a wide area of space for a disabled ship.  (I mean, heck, it can turn a 90's era pager into an FTL communicator, what _can't_ it do?)

Comment: She already had contact with the Avengers core team via the post-credit scene in her origin movie. It's likely she's been looking for any sign of known superheroes left.

Comment: It's also Rocket's ship. He probably had some sort of beacon or whatever

Comment: @AzorAhai wasn't it actually Quill's ship?  (nitpik) lol

Comment: @enorl76 Well, either way, it's not a surprise they could find it given Rocket's tools

Comment: It's Day 22 *From Iron Man/Strange/Spidey/Quill/Nebula's encounter on Titan*.  Actually I'm not sure about that; Stark does know about the Snap, so he might've been counting from there.  That said, we don't know how fast Snap effects propagate through the universe.

Comment: @enorl76  Mal: "While I'm gone, it's your ship.  If I get in trouble, you come rescue me, y'hear?"..... Zoe:  "What? And risk my ship?"

Comment: Not so sure about this... When did Captain Marvel arrive on Earth in the IW post credits sequence?  I think we can assume she set off to find them pretty much right after, if nothing else, it gives us an upper bound.

Comment: @Baldrickk In about the amount of time it would have taken the pager to exhaust its batteries normally, apparently.  They found the pager and hooked it up to a long term power supply to keep it broadcasting, then it suddenly stopped and were like "wait, what, didn't we just fix that?" and then she shows up Horror Movie style. I don't recall them thinking *their* hookup had run out or failed, just that the pager's own battery had run out and somehow they goofed on giving it a continual power supply.

Comment: I can only imagine how boring it would get flying through space for 12 hours...